# Basic username-password authentication on gitorious

Tags: authentication, http-basic-authentication, git

I recently set up my own server that is supposed to host some git repositories. I installed gitorious there. It is almost perfect. The one thing that I am struggling with right now is how can I make users authenticate using their username and password instead of public ssh key? The same way that GitHub lets do that. It is very important for me, not to force users to generate ssh keys. I looked for the answer everywhere, but couldn't fint it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: When did GitHub start accepting username/password for authentication? Or do you mean when accessing the web interface?

Comment: I don't know when. I mean when pushing. You just use https://username:password@github.com/etc/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked, but in general you probably need some kind of PAM plugin for that.

Someone describes how to to do it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gitorious/3tiS-zk-PuI/xSrEwE8tHB0J), but I haven't tried it, so YMMV.